# How to solve this : occurred evaluating project :app

Tags: android, vlc

when I use vlc-android-demo-master on the Android Studio,This problem happened:

```
Error:(16, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
```

> Could not find method runProguard() for arguments [false] on BuildType_Decorated{name=release, debuggable=false, testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false, pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false, renderscriptOptimLevel=3, minifyEnabled=false, zipAlignEnabled=true, signingConfig=null, embedMicroApp=true, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.

But I don't know how it is produced, and how to solve.But I think this may be related to gradle.this is my build.gradle code.

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.nmbb.vlc"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}


}


dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
}
```

[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Im95W.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29GCM.png)

Answer (score 0):

change `runProguard` to `minifyEnabled` in gradle

Comment: thank you ! it works now.Could you like to tell me why？

Comment: runProguard was renamed to minifyEnabled in version 0.14.0